# paypal-checkout-sdk Capture function is captured once only how to fixed fatal error when it is occuring second time

Tags: paypal

I am using paypal-checkout-sdk for server side configuration.
I have used custom button. On submission of that i am creating order
with below code

```
$environment = new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
$client = new PayPalHttpClient($environment);
$request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
$request->prefer('return=representation');
$request->body = [
                     "intent" => "CAPTURE",
                     "purchase_units" => [[
                         "reference_id" => "test_ref_id1",
                         "amount" => [
                             "value" => "100.00",
                             "currency_code" => "USD"
                         ]
                     ]],
                     "application_context" => [
                          "cancel_url" => "https://example.com/cancel",
                          "return_url" => "https://example.com/return"
                     ]
                 ];

try {
    // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
    $response = $client->execute($request);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
    echo "</pre>";
    //exit();
    // If call returns body in response, you can get the deserialized version from the result attribute of the response
    if(isset($response->result->links[1]->href) && !empty($response->result->links[1]->href)){
        //echo $response->result->links[1]->href;
         //header('Location:'.$response->result->links[1]->href);
         //die();
    }

}catch (HttpException $ex) {
    //echo $ex->statusCode;
    //print_r($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Then redirect it to paypal with approved url. After coming from that if i am using capture class to
capture data.In that i am receiving response properly.

```
$request = new OrdersCaptureRequest("6UD13042B02825225");

$request->prefer('return=representation');

try {
    // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
    $response = $client->execute($request);
    print_r($response);
    // If call returns body in response, you can get the deserialized version from the result attribute of the response
    if ($response->statusCode == 201)
    {
        print_r($response);
    }
}catch (HttpException $ex) {
    $message = json_decode($ex->getMessage(), true);
    //echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), "\n";
    print_r($message);
    print "Status Code: {$ex->statusCode}\n";
}

Response sample.
PayPalHttp\HttpResponse Object ( [statusCode] => 201 [result] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 6UD13042B02825225 [intent] => CAPTURE [status] => COMPLETED [purchase_units] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [reference_id] => test_ref_id1 [amount] => stdClass Object ( [currency_code] => USD [value] => 100.00 ) [
```

If I am trying to run this above code for OrderCapture for the same order it is showing an error like this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PayPalHttp\HttpException: {"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":[{"issue":"ORDER_ALREADY_CAPTURED","description":"Order already captured.If 'intent=CAPTURE' only one capture per order is allowed."}],"message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"cfdc8ac1d115b","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-ORDER_ALREADY_CAPTURED","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]} in
```

I am not sure how to fix this error. I want to capture it multiple times.

Comment: "I want to capture it multiple times." -- what makes you think you can capture an order multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

When using intent:capture, only one capture can be made for an order, for the full amount. This is what the payer approved when they went through the checkout approval flow.

You cannot capture multiple times in this situation, since that was not approved by the payer.

You need a new order (and to get it approved) for a new capture.

Comment: Thanks, Preston for your reply I appreciate that. But what if I want to save results after payment. What method I should use. It should be on multiple bases.

Comment: Multiple databases? I'm not sure why you would need to repeat the API request for this. One request should be enough, then send it everywhere you need. But if you really want to repeat the request and just get duplicate replies, you can try with API idempotency by specifying a PayPal-Request-Id header that is the same for all repeat requests (maybe make it be the OrderID plus some prefix): https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/#api-idempotency

Comment: There is also a get API call: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2#orders_get -- but, you should not be depending on the PayPal API returning the status of an order for long after it's been captured. Make a record of it as soon as possible (preferably immediately after the first capture), and ideally you store this information everywhere and never have to use another API call again for that order so long as it remains complete

Comment: I am not using multiple databases. I am able to capture it immediately after it's returning from PayPal. But in some cases, for example, If I get a MySQL error while inserting this captured data. So at that time, I am not able to capture my payment details again. It's through fatal error. So i was not sure how to tackle this fatal error. But I think this API-idempotency will be useful to me.

Comment: Thank you @Preston PHX  i am able to fix my issue